# xpath, nodes from two different paths

Tags: xml, xpath

How would I get xpath nodes for 'div/a' or 'a'?

I have tried the following without success, and am having trouble following the documentation on w3schools as it lacks examples.

```
el.xpath( 'div/a or a' )
```

Comment: Try //a, that means all "a" nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I dont want all "a" nodes.  In my use case, el is a <td> element.  And I only want elements from within it

Comment: What about `.//a`? Returns all anchor tags that are in the table cell's subtree.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more info about your intensions (e.g. input xml) but you can try `div/a|a`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need union operator `|`, i.e.:

```
'div/a | a'
```